# Migration of complex FLASH animations to HTML5

Tags: html, flash, migration

so let's get to the thing. I have to estimate a project that's main goal is to migrate from FLASH interactive and complex animations into HTML5.

As far as I've read there are plenty of questions how to do it... so I've researched there is Swiffy / Wallaby / Adobe Flash Professional Toolkit for CreateJS and Online converters and here goes the BUT... but many persons said it won't handle more complex FLASH animations (only simple ones).

So the question is: Does someone have an experience with such a migration, is there a non-manual way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you mean automated by non-manual, I'm afraid there isn't.

Comment: Do you have a link to the site/code that exists in Flash/AS? It may not be as complex as you think.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the sources for now and the flash animations are accessible only after the registration process. If I'll get the code I'll try to update the topic asap with the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a non-manual way to do it for most Flash animations that contain some ActionScript, as well as a limited set of more interactive applications. If ease is your first concern, try the latest release of [Swiffy](https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/) (5.0 when you wrote your question and as of this response). Swiffy supports a [substantial feature set of ActionScript 3](https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/actionscript3.html), more than enough for navigational controls.

Drawbacks:

- The level of snappiness may be unsatisfactory; I have been happy with functionality of some simple game conversions but they are sluggish.
- The end product is SVG, so you'll also have to contend with unsupported browsers.
- Changes to artwork will probably need to be made to the natives first, then re-exported. Otherwise, there is a hefty JSON config you can edit (and watch it blow up).
- You may need to get under the hood with sound (I use SoundManager2).

I am less familiar with the Wallaby/CreateJS workflow but ActionScript support during export from Flash is extremely limited. Essentially, it enables you to export your asset library for use with CreateJS on the JavaScript side.